# Align all equal signs in array of equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to align all equal signs in a stack of two equations so that they occupy the same areas evenly?
This is my current code:

```
\begin{eqnarray} 
m \Vec{a} \cdot \Hat{u}_L = - m L \Dot{\theta}^2 &=& \Vec{T_f} \cdot \Hat{u}_L + m \Vec{g} \cdot \Hat{u}_L \\
m \Vec{a} \cdot \Hat{u}_\theta = m L \Ddot{\theta} &=& \underbrace{\Vec{T_f} \cdot \Hat{u}_\theta}_{=0} + m \Vec{g} \cdot \Hat{u}_\theta
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Never use `eqnarray`.

Comment: If you use `align` environment, but whit only one ampersand on left of the equal?, like `m \Vec{a} \cdot \Hat{u}_L = - m L \Dot{\theta}^2 &= \Vec{T_f} \cdot \Hat{u}_L + m \Vec{g} \cdot \Hat{u}_L`

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to replace `\Vec{T_f}` with `\vec{T}_f`. Also, there's no point in writing `\Hat`, `\Dot` and `\Ddot` instead of `\hat`, `\dot`, and `\ddot`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you employ an `alignat{3}` environment, so that you can place alignment points at both sets of `=` symbols as well as at the `+` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_L 
  &=  - m L \dot{\theta}^2 
  &&= \vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_L 
  &&+ m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_L \\
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta 
  &=  \phantom{-}m L \ddot{\theta} 
  &&= {\underbrace{\vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_\theta}_{=0}} 
  &&+ m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For complex alignments, I suggest to use `IEEEeqnarray` that, despite its name, is perfectly safe, whereas `eqnarray` isn't (buggy and deprecated).

I provide two realizations for the middle term, take your pick.

With `C` you get a column where to set relation or operation symbols with appropriate spacing; `lcr` have the obvious meaning.

I suggest a `\ubrace` command to replace `\underbrace` with its weird syntax and also weird behavior if not enclosed in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCcClCl}
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_L 
  &=&  - m L \dot{\theta}^2 
  &=& \vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_L
  &+& m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_L \\
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta 
  &=&  m L \ddot{\theta} 
  &=& \ubrace{\vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_\theta}{=0}
  &+& m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rClClCl}
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_L 
  &=&  - m L \dot{\theta}^2 
  &=& \vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_L
  &+& m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_L \\
m \vec{a} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta 
  &=& \hphantom{-}m L \ddot{\theta} 
  &=& \ubrace{\vec{T}_f \cdot \hat{u}_\theta}{=0}
  &+& m \vec{g} \cdot \hat{u}_\theta
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just in passing, `\Vec`, `\Hat`, `\Dot` and `\Ddot` are exactly the same as the uncapitalized commands. They exist only for historical reasons; use the all-lowercase versions.